# React native JSON Parse error:Unrecognized token '<'

Tags: react-native

i want to ask json parse api link must be hosting under by https?
i got this error because my hosting was not secure?
anyone know this problem?
this is my code:

```
fetch('http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/reactnative/register.php', {
            method: 'post',
            header:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                name: userName,
                email: userEmail,
                password: userPassword,
            })
```

but my link cant run https:// on the browser
Is this cause me cant parse the data to the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the response you're receiving being an html page. Make sure your server is set up to receive the information you're trying to send in JSON form. You could try sending your data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (in case that's how the server is expecting the data) like so:

`` body: `name=${userName}&email=${userEmail}&password=${userPassword}` ``

Comment: Like this?
fetch('http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/reactnative/register.php', {
   method: 'post',
   header:{
    'Accept': 'application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-type': 'application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   body: 'name=${userName}&email=${userEmail}&password=${userPassword}'
   
  })

Comment: Correct, but make sure you are using backticks instead of single quotes, because that's what the syntax for template literals looks like. You could also use regular concatenation if you prefer, like so: `body: 'name=' + userName + '&email=' + userEmail + '&password=' + userPassword`

Also, your `'Accept'` header just indicates what type of information you can accept as the client. If you are not sure what kind of response the server sends back, I recommend removing that header and only including `'Content-type'`